# c# localisation reading wrong resource.resx

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I am implementing a localisation feature that formats the date of calendar events differently depending on the locale e,g 5/10/17 for en-US, 10/5/17 for en-AU etc.

It is correctly identifying the locale as en-AU (checked the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`), but it is using the date format from the en-US `resources.resx`.

What could I be missing?

I am formatting a DateTime object to a string and storing in a class member field, this is done in a ViewModel. 
The `resources.resx` files are in a folder called Localization. 
I have referenced the localization folder and ViewModel in the xaml view.

Comment: Have you set the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, too?

Comment: Yes I have set that as well

Comment: Turns out that I needed another internal library file from within our code base, dw then